# How to implement synonyms using elastic search in C#?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am very new to elastic search. I need to implement synonym functionality, means if someone is searching for "blue" he must also get results for "navy".  Can I get an explanation about how we can achieve this? Also, what are the ways if we want to create synonyms for multiple words. Thank You.

Comment: You will have to create a dictionary which is having each keyword as key and all synonyms as its value in a list or array. So whenever somebody searches for a keyword we will return search results for all the values present for that particular key.

Comment: I'm nto sure how to do this in elastic search, but as a general method, I would use a thesaurus lookup for each word, then storing the results in a dictionary. When you construct your search term, you can apply a weight to the words such that your main term is given a higher priority than the synonyms. An online thesaurus lookup service in C# is explained in this article - https://en.code-bude.net/tag/thesaurus-c/

Comment: Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/synonyms.html